# Fetching the Odata query parameter in code

Tags: rest, api, odata

I have a rest Get method Ex:-

```
public IQueryable<Test> GetTest() {
            return _service.GetAll();
        }
```

I want to fetch the query parameter in code which was the part of the request url, I cant give OdataQueryOption parameter in the method like GetTest(OdataQueryOption 
 op).

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're implementing an `ODataController` you should be able to access `this.Request.RequestUri.Query`. If you want the name/value pairs you should use `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to get a `NameValueCollection`.